How to configure tracing_subscriber output format (json or plain text) based on env variable?
I am trying to set tracing format based on variable and I want something like that:
    let tracing_layer = {
        if env::var("LOG_FORMAT").is_ok_and(|format| format == "json") {
            tracing_subscriber::fmt::layer().json();
        } else {
            tracing_subscriber::fmt::layer();
        }
    };

    tracing_subscriber::registry()
        .with(tracing_subscriber::EnvFilter::try_from_default_env()
            .unwrap_or_else(|_| "api_gateway=debug,axum=debug,tower_http=debug".into()))
        .with(tracing_layer)
        .init();

And got:
the trait bound (): __tracing_subscriber_Layer<tracing_subscriber::layer::Layered<EnvFilter, Registry>> is not satisfied
the following other types implement trait __tracing_subscriber_Layer<S>:
  DynFilterFn<S, F, R>
  Box<(dyn __tracing_subscriber_Layer<S> + Send + Sync + 'static)>
  Box<L>
  FilterFn<F>
  tracing::level_filters::LevelFilter
  EnvFilter
  Filtered<L, F, S>
  Targets
and 6 others

I can't figure out what generic type for tracing_layer should look like. I understand it's tracing_subscriber::fmt::Layer<S: tracing::Subscriber>. Perhaps, there're some better solutions to set output format.
I know I can do it this way:
    if env::var("LOG_FORMAT").is_ok_and(|log| log == "json") {
        tracing_subscriber::registry()
            .with(tracing_subscriber::EnvFilter::try_from_default_env()
                .unwrap_or_else(|_| "api_gateway=debug,axum=debug,tower_http=debug".into()))
            .with(tracing_subscriber::fmt::layer().json())
            .init();
    } else {
        tracing_subscriber::registry()
            .with(tracing_subscriber::EnvFilter::try_from_default_env()
                .unwrap_or_else(|_| "api_gateway=debug,axum=debug,tower_http=debug".into()))
            .with(tracing_subscriber::fmt::layer())
            .init();
    }

But it seems messy

The current way to handle this is by using the Layer::boxed method. The linked documentation explains the details, but in short you can call .boxed() on your layers which (from the docs):

Erases the type of this Layer, returning a Boxed dyn Layer trait object.
This can be used when a function returns a Layer which may be of one of several types, or when a Layer subscriber has a very long type signature.

Your original code would become:
let tracing_layer = {
    if env::var("LOG_FORMAT").is_ok_and(|format| format == "json") {
        tracing_subscriber::fmt::layer().json().boxed()
    } else {
        tracing_subscriber::fmt::layer().boxed()
    }
};

tracing_subscriber::registry()
    .with(tracing_subscriber::EnvFilter::try_from_default_env()
        .unwrap_or_else(|_| "api_gateway=debug,axum=debug,tower_http=debug".into()))
    .with(tracing_layer)
    .init();


Box<dyn Layer<S>> impls Layer<S>, so:
    let tracing_layer = {
        if env::var("LOG_FORMAT").is_ok_and(|format| format == "json") {
            Box::new(tracing_subscriber::fmt::layer().json()) as Box<dyn Layer<Registry>>
        } else {
            Box::new(tracing_subscriber::fmt::layer())
        }
    };

    tracing_subscriber::registry()
        .with(tracing_subscriber::EnvFilter::try_from_default_env()
            .unwrap_or_else(|_| "api_gateway=debug,axum=debug,tower_http=debug".into()))
        .with(tracing_layer)
        .init();

